# SwiftUI and Core Data — Publishers not working and context not detecting changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an application in which I use SwiftUI and Core Data. In the Core Data datamodel, I have an Entity, `Record`, which has various attributes, two of which are of a custom class type, who's purpose is to act as a wrapper for an array. These classes both contain a property which is an array of another custom class type (`Array<[Class]>`). Some of properties in the definitions of the aforementioned class types are prefixed with the `@Published` property wrapper, so that the view will update when these properties change, along with the context. Rather unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case — and I can't work out why! I have tried to work around this by having a custom delegate to manually call `objectWillChange.send()`, but this doesn't feel very clean, nor does it register changes with the context.

The application can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Timekeeper), the relevant data model classes are in [this directory](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Timekeeper/tree/master/Timekeeper/Model/NSObject), and the relevant view classes are [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Timekeeper/blob/master/Timekeeper/View/ContentView.swift) and [RecordDetailView.swift](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Timekeeper/blob/master/Timekeeper/View/RecordDetailView.swift) (I have commented the `[SwiftUIView]_Previews` structs because I'm not quite sure how to get the previews to work with the Core Data container). I won't post many code-snippets here, as they are somewhat dependent on each other and there is too much to form a concise question.

Below is the definition of one of these "wrapper" classes:

```swift
import Foundation

@objc(Nodes)
public class Nodes: NSObject, NSSecureCoding, ObservableObject {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    @Published public var nodes = [Node]()

    public enum Keys: String {
        case nodes = "nodes"
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(nodes: [Node]) {
        super.init()
        self.nodes = nodes
        for node in nodes {
            node.delegates.append(self)
        }
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(nodes, forKey: Keys.nodes.rawValue)
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        let nodes = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.nodes.rawValue) as! [Node]
        self.init(nodes: nodes)
    }
}

extension Nodes: NodeDelegate {
    func didUpdateNode(node: Node) {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

And below is the definition of the Array type:

```swift
import Foundation

@objc(Node)
public class Node: NSObject, NSSecureCoding, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    public var id = UUID()
    var delegates: [NodeDelegate] = [NodeDelegate]() {
        didSet {
            delegates.forEach { $0.didUpdateNode(node: self) }
        }
    }
    @Published private var x = "0" {
        didSet {
            delegates.forEach { $0.didUpdateNode(node: self) }
        }
    }
    @Published private var y = "0" {
        didSet {
            delegates.forEach { $0.didUpdateNode(node: self) }
        }
    }
    var xDouble: Double {
        set {
            x = String(newValue)
        }
        get {
            if let x = Double(x) {
                return x
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    var yDouble: Double {
        set {
            y = String(newValue)
        }
        get {
            if let y = Double(y) {
                return y
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    var xString: String {
        get {
            x
        }
        set {
            x = newValue
        }
    }
    var yString: String {
        get {
            y
        }
        set {
            y = newValue
        }
       }

    public enum Keys: String {
        case x = "x"
        case y = "y"
        case delegates = "delegates"
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(x: String, y: String) {
        self.init()
        xString = x
        yString = y
    }

    convenience init(x: Double, y: Double) {
        self.init()
        self.xDouble = x
        self.yDouble = y
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(x, forKey: Keys.x.rawValue)
        coder.encode(y, forKey: Keys.y.rawValue)
        coder.encode(delegates, forKey: Keys.delegates.rawValue)
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        let x = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.x.rawValue) as! String
        let y = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.y.rawValue) as! String
        let delegates = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.delegates.rawValue) as! [NodeDelegate]
        self.init(x: x, y: y)
        self.delegates = delegates
    }
}
```

On another note, there are also several *really* horrible UI glitches which I do not understand, for example, sometimes when tapping on a `RecordThumbnailView` from a `ContentView` it will do nothing, but then when tapping on a different `RecordThumbnailView` it will suddenly push all of the `RecordDetailView`s which correspond to all of the unresponsive `RecordThumbnailView`s. In addition, when performing this same segue, the `ChartViewControllerView` will jolt upwards very quickly, and will be hidden behind the navigation bar.

If you know of any ways to overcome these issues, I'd appreciate the assistance — I've been staring at these problems for several days!

Comment: I had a look at your project. For me it looks like a mix of different contradicting principles. E.g. ObservableObject (Combine) but no ObservedObject counterpart in SwiftUI view, @Published variables with "didSet" calls. A lot of environmentObject modifiers also for direct child views. I suggest to clear the architecture in a more SwiftUI/Combine like way where a class implementing ObservableObject protocol has an ObservedObject counterpart in the SwiftUI view and EnvironmentObject will be used for global managers/services only and parent child hierarchies such as lists just pass the record.

Comment: @berni Thanks for your feedback! Do you know of any examples I could use to help guide me?

Comment: Is this perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357414/changes-to-swiftui-fetchrequest-not-triggering-view-refresh ?