# SwiftUI - NavigationLink Content loaded too early

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a basic list in my first View as Follows:

```
func buildList(sections: [Client]) -> some View {
    let list = List {
        ForEach(sections) { client in
            Section(header: Text(client.name)) {
                ForEach(client.projects) { project in
                    NavigationLink(destination: BuildsRouter.build(forProject: project)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Test \(project.id)").fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return  list
}
```

I'm using `NavigationLink` to provide the details view for my `Project` object.

Thing is, when I make a Memory analysis graph I can see that `BuildsView` ( created from `BuildsRouter.build(forProject: project)` are **created before I actually tap the navigation Link**.

Question:
**Is there any way to create the details View once the link is tapped?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357414/changes-to-swiftui-fetchrequest-not-triggering-view-refresh Wrapping the `NavigationLink` in a `LazyView<Content: View>` is a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

True, I wrote a blog post on [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-navigation-links-and-the-common-pitfalls-faced-505cbfd8029b). You can wrap the destination views in a Lazy Container as a workaround. Update: From Xcode 11.4.1 NavigationLinks are lazy by default.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I am on Xcode 11.4.1 and NavigationLink Destination Views are being loaded at App start up.

Comment: Strange, is the iOS version 13.4.1 or above as well?

Comment: Yep. It is not in every case either, some NavigationLInks are loading at App startup and some are being lazy loaded, I'm yet to determine the pattern.  I am using the objc.io solution to fix this at the moment.

Comment: Even if it's fixed in 11.4.1, does this mean we need to wrap all NavigationLink views in lazy loading wrappers since lower versions of iOS 13 on devices would still have this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping them in Lazy as the issue popped up again in 11.5

Comment: This is great workaround for lazy loading. Thanks!