# Swift UI - Using Navigation View and a Navigation Link - Creating view models before the Navigation Link is Activated

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

Inside a navigation view, I have a navigation link that shows the details of the item selected. Every detail view has its own view model. The problem is when I do it this way and check my memory graph I can see all my detail view models have been instantiated and stored in memory even before I make a selection from the list. I'm wondering if this is some sort of a sort UI bug when using the navigation View/Link or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006246/swiftui-observedobject-viewmodel-in-detail-view-of-list-never-released/63006377?r=SearchResults#63006377

Answer (score 0):

Check NavigationLazyView:
[SwiftUI NavigationLink loads destination view immediately, without clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594159/swiftui-navigationlink-loads-destination-view-immediately-without-clicking)

e.g.
NavigationLink("SomeLinkLabel", destination: NavigationLazyView(Text("SomeLink"))

edit: been using this for a while, I forgot this is not part of standard SwiftUI

Comment: What's NavigationLazyView?

Comment: sorry, clarified in the answer